# how to display html content inside displayfield?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

i have a form that contain `htmleditor` field...
in report module, the content/value of thoose field must be readable and printable
so i am using [someone answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7014382/495571) to make it printable..

at first, i just make it using displayfield, and just load it using `getForm().setValues()`
it done,..
this is the [simple](http://jsfiddle.net/mohammad_erdin/EVYm3/) demo

but now i have a problem...
try to insert bullet/numbering...
and then klik "set and display"...
there is no bullet exist..

i think this is because in `main.css` they set `li{ list-style: none;}`.
how to fix it??? how to display htmleditor content in displayfield??

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to include `ext-all.css` in printing frame. When you remove it, the bullets will be visible. Another thing - why you use this display field? You can print content right away without setting it to displayfield. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/EVYm3/5/

Comment: thanks for reply.. you're right to remove css in window print, but when i remove it, the window print is malformat... and abaout displayfield,.. my form is like this : http://jsfiddle.net/mohammad_erdin/EVYm3/6/ . so i need to show to the user the other displayfields.. not only the htmleditor